# What are the boundary values of x and y in DECIMAL(x, y) in MySQL datatype declaration?

Tags: mysql, decimal

I have got the following UDF

```
drop function if exists getCurrency$$

create function getCurrency(dt datetime, x decimal(19,4), y decimal(19, 4)) 
returns decimal(10,4) reads sql data
begin
     declare currencyval decimal(10,4);

     /* Some conditions */
     select case when dt = "2000-12-31" then 0 else round((x/y), 4) into currencyval;

     return currencyval;
end$$
```

Sometimes this UDF throws Data truncation error. 
I can resolve the issue but the before even that I want some information regarding the Decimal data type and the significance of 10, 4 in the parameters.

It would be good if you give some examples with the boundary conditions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`10, 4` means 6 digits (integer part) before point and 4 after (fractional part).

So the biggest possible number you can return is `999999.9999`

In your particular case it is not possible to say what values are boundary for `x` and/or `y`, but you can check if the return value (`currencyval`) is out of `-999999.9999 .. 999999.9999` range.

Btw, if you're asking about `x` and `y` in `DECIMAL (x, y)` records, then:

- `x = 1..65`
- `y = 0..30 && y <= x`

References:

- [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual :: 11.2.2 Fixed-Point Types (Exact Value) - `DECIMAL`, `NUMERIC`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Comment: This link is dead, but the answer is still here. Also 10 is there for 6? I would expect from this example `L_NUM NUMBER(10,4) carries precision up to 10 digits, where 4 digits can be placed after the decimal.` to this not be the case ([source](http://psoug.org/definition/number.htm)).

Comment: @gsamaras decumal(10, 4) means 6 for numerical part, 4 for fractional part. The link is fixed, thanks.